# Best way to set "networkaddress.cache.ttl"

Tags: java, elasticsearch, ttl

I need to set the Java setting `networkaddress.cache.ttl`.  I know very little about Java so I'm asking, what is Best Practice for setting this value?

I know that the setting lives in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` but customizing this file doesn't seem very excellent.  Is there a place for custom Java settings?

This is for Elasticsearch, so if I could glom it into the ES init script or something, that would be better, but I don't know how to set this on-the-fly.

Thanks in advance Java people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't want  to set security properties file then you can set `sun.net.inetaddr.ttl` property on the JVM command line with `-Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=0`.

However, the preferred way is to use the security properties file (ref:[Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html)) because `sun.net.inetaddr.ttl` may not be supported in future releases.

Comment: Preferred by whom?

Comment: Preferred by Oracle; see definition of this property in [the JavaSE 7 networking guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html).